# What does ${50}\choose{4}$ mean in statistics?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, statistics, binomial-coefficients, combinations, factorial

I have a test tomorrow in statistics and was wondering what the following means?

$$\binom{50}{4}$$

My professor along with most of my classmates have a calculator they can just plug that into. The professor never went into depth on what it means and how to figure it out with a normal ti-30.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Number of ways of selecting 4 obje ts out of 50. Look up nCr

Comment: On the TI-30, press the top number ($50$), then the PROB key to bring up the probability menu.  Press the right arrow and then enter to select nCr or combination.  Then press the bottom number ($4$) and then press $=$.

Answer (score 3):

${50}\choose{4}$ is read "$50$ choose $4$" and is the number of ways to choose $4$ things from $50$ things, where order doesn't matter. Most graphing calculators will have a button for this, if not there is the formula:

$${{n}\choose{k}} =\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

where $n!=n\times (n-1)\times\cdots\times 1$.

Comment: awww ok that's what it is, looks like something i use when I use beizier curves in my computer graphics class. Thanks man!

Comment: Note that factorials can get really large and exceed a calculator's memory for integers, even when $\binom{n}{k}$ does not. So for example, if I did not have a special button, I'd compute $\binom{50}{4}$ as $\frac{\overbrace{50\cdot49\cdot48\cdot47}^{\text{4 factors}}}{4!}$ rather than $\frac{50!}{4!\cdot46!}$.

Comment: On top of "the order doesn't matter", it is worth mentioning: 1. Without replacement. 2. $50$ **unique** things.

Answer (score 2):

**Binomial Coefficient or Combination**

Wikipedia words it quite nicely:

> $\binom{n}{k}$ is read as "$n$ choose $k$", because there are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to choose $k$ elements, disregarding their order, from a set of $n$ elements.

I'd bet that most calculators use this efficient method,
$$\binom{n}{k} = \prod\limits_{i=1}^k \frac{n+1-i}{i}$$
So for your example, we have
$$\binom{50}{4} = \prod\limits_{i=1}^4 \frac{51-i}{i}=\frac{50\cdot 49\cdot 48\cdot 47}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4}=230,300$$
Which means that there are 230,300 ways to choose 4 elements from a set of 50 elements, disregarding their order. The more common but less efficient method of computing this is
$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\quad\mbox{for}\quad 0\leq k\leq n$$
So for your example, we have
$$\binom{50}{4} = \frac{50!}{4!46!}=\frac{50\cdot 49\cdot 48\cdot 47\cdot 46!}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 46!}=230,300$$
Have a look at [Binomial Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), [Combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) and [Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) for a better understanding.